# How to deploy an application on heroku - ReactJS & ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, heroku

I tried to deploy my applications on Heroku but when I open the app https://site-web-france.herokuapp.com/ it displayed :

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
Heroku logs --tail
```

I feel it runs the server on port 5000 but my client app on port 3000 doesn't run.

MyProject/package.json :

```
{
  "name": "site-web-france",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd client && yarn start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\"",
    "dev:server": "cd client && yarn build && cd .. && yarn start",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.6",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0"
  }
}
```

MyProject/client/package.json :

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0-14",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-11",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.1.0-11",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.7",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-google-auth": "^0.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^1.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.13",
    "video-react": "^0.9.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
}
```

When I start Heroku local I see this :

```
MB-Pro:MyProjects admin$ heroku local
    [WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
    [OKAY] package.json file found - trying 'npm start'
    [WARN] No ENV file found
    [WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
    [OKAY] package.json file found - trying 'npm start'
    13:23:40 web.1   |  > site-web-france@1.0.0 start /Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects
    13:23:40 web.1   |  > node server.js
    13:23:41 web.1   |  (node:79181) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
    13:23:41 web.1   |  Listening on port 5000
    13:23:42 web.1   |  { MongoError: Authentication failed.
    13:23:42 web.1   |      at /Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:580:63
    13:23:42 web.1   |      at authenticateStragglers (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:503:16)
    13:23:42 web.1   |      at Connection.messageHandler (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:539:5)
    13:23:42 web.1   |      at emitMessageHandler (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:309:10)
    13:23:42 web.1   |      at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:452:17)
    13:23:42 web.1   |      at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    13:23:42 web.1   |      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    13:23:42 web.1   |      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    13:23:42 web.1   |      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
    13:23:42 web.1   |      at TCP.onread (net.js:639:20)
    13:23:42 web.1   |    name: 'MongoError',
    13:23:42 web.1   |    message: 'Authentication failed.',
    13:23:42 web.1   |    ok: 0,
    13:23:42 web.1   |    errmsg: 'Authentication failed.',
    13:23:42 web.1   |    code: 18,
    13:23:42 web.1   |    codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed',
    13:23:42 web.1   |    operationTime:
    13:23:42 web.1   |     Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 9, high_: 1534418622 },
    13:23:42 web.1   |    '$clusterTime':
    13:23:42 web.1   |     { clusterTime:
    13:23:42 web.1   |        Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 9, high_: 1534418622 },
    13:23:42 web.1   |       signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] } },
    13:23:42 web.1   |    [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
    13:23:54 web.1   |  TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
    13:23:54 web.1   |      at app.get (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/server.js:95:18)
    13:23:54 web.1   |      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    13:23:54 web.1   |      at next (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    13:23:54 web.1   |      at Route.dispatch (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    13:23:54 web.1   |      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    13:23:54 web.1   |      at /Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    13:23:54 web.1   |      at Function.process_params (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    13:23:54 web.1   |      at next (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    13:23:54 web.1   |      at urlencodedParser (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:91:7)
    13:23:54 web.1   |      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    13:23:54 web.1   |      at trim_prefix (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    13:23:54 web.1   |      at /Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    13:23:54 web.1   |      at Function.process_params (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    13:23:54 web.1   |      at next (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    13:23:54 web.1   |      at expressInit (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    13:23:54 web.1   |      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/site-web-france/informatique/MyProjects/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    ^C[WARN] Interrupted by User
    [DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
    MB-Pro:MyProjects admin$ 13:30:19 web.1   Exited with exit code null
```

Do you know why that doesn't work? What needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

As I see here, you have a Node.js+Mongoose server application and React client app, so you try to run concurrently on single Heroku app. From my experience I will say that I could not configure the application in that way. If you want to consume your time, read [this article about how to run two servers on a single Heroku dyno](https://medium.com/@nadayar/heroku-fu-multiple-servers-on-one-dyno-6fc68d57b373) and try to reproduce it.

The best solution will be to divide client and server parts into two separate projects and host them severally.

If to speak about your local attempt, I see that you have no ENV file and a Mongoose auth error. Seems like you have your connection string `undefined`.

Comment: It hasn't possibility of added to `MyProject/package.json` a line who makes works correctly,  in production ?

Comment: I'm afraid not.